# Calendar extender not popping up

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have no idea why my ajax calender extender not popping up with I click on my textbox

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>



        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>


        Please select Start date<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxstart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="TextBoxstart_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
            Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="TextBoxstart">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>


    Please Select End Date <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxend" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="TextBoxend_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBoxend">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

When I click in the textbox nothing happens. I have also included the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll in the bin folder and nothing. I have other projects with this control and no problem at all. I have also used  and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

from your current code, TextBoxstart is not in the code snippet. Only "TextBoxend".

The end date should work as you have the calendarextender's TargetControlID set to it. Just not for TextBoxstart.

Comment: Dont know why it wasn't showing on the page. I have updated my code and none of the textboxes work

Comment: your code is invalid. you have 2 textboxes named "Textboxend" - this will cause a runtime error. I STILL see no "TextBoxstart"

Comment: typepo I was trying to paste the code on here but it wouldn't show as code. Textboxstart is actually what I have and it still doesn't work